# android: how to run ui test in java

Tags: java, android, testing, coded-ui-tests

In [android dev](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html), google just tell me how to run ui test with cli like following:

```
adb shell uiautomator runtest LaunchSettings.jar -c com.uia.example.my.LaunchSettings
```

i hope i can run ui test like following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    UITestRunner.run(uiTestFile);
}
```

**my question is:** how to run android ui test in java?

**i hope** i can debug ui test with intellij idea or eclipse and encapsulate it.

Answer (score 0):

The uiautomator test case doesn't need runners unlike junit test. You can write test code (in android dev's example, LaunchSettings.java) and compile it, then put it to your device with your app. See the example test code. http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html#sample

Comment: is there way to debug ui test on intellij or idea? writting ui test in java is aimed to debug it

Comment: Use -e debug command or this link may be helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978292/how-do-i-debug-uiautomator-scripts-with-eclipse